# Japanese idiom equivalent to “Fat Fingered"

Tags: translation, idioms

Is there a Japanese idiom equivalent to "fat fingered"?

In other words, an idiom which means "to make a mistake when performing a task that requires using ones finger". This is often used in reference to buttons, switches, keyboard keys, and more recently, touch screens.

Comment: Probably no exact match exists, but surely you can use the word for 'clumsy' instead?

Comment: Haha, I was thinking of this the other day for some reason!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way:

> 操作｛そうさ｝ミス（をした）

Also:

> 押｛お｝し間｛ま｝違｛ちが｝えた

For example: https://matome.naver.jp/odai/2135281310283618301

That's an article about how to cancel when you pushed the wrong floor button on an elevator.

Consider also:

> 踏｛ふ｝み間｛ま｝違｛ちが｝えた (often meaning to mistake the gas pedal for the brake while driving, like ブレーキとアクセルを踏み間違えた)

For example: http://www.saitama-np.co.jp/news/2016/12/18/04.html

Answer (score 1):

不器用{ぶきよう} is a common way to describe someone with poor dexterity.